# Create ListItem in Sharepoint C# Using Client-Object Model

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I'm new in this theme but I search a lot I mean really lot before I asked it here. So my problem is that, when I create ListItem in my app and set the Fields that are required, everything looks all right. I can see the ListItem in my List with proper fields if I go to Sharepoint Online. But when I click on the ListItem the Fields are empty and on the top of the page is an error which says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." I don't know if the issue is happening cos of my code or there is an issue with Sharepoint settings? I followed most of the guides here to go as far as I'm now. My code below.

```
        SP.List targetList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");

        ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new ListItemCreationInformation();
        ListItem newListItem = targetList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);

        newListItem["Title"] = "Test_title";
        newListItem["EAN_x0020_k_x00f3_d"] = "AnotherCodeWhichIsRequired";
        newListItem.Update();

        string strFilePath = @"PathToMyPDF";

        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strFilePath);

        using (System.IO.MemoryStream mStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            SP.AttachmentCreationInformation aci = new SP.AttachmentCreationInformation();
            aci.ContentStream = mStream;
            aci.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFilePath);

            newListItem.AttachmentFiles.Add(aci);

            newListItem.Update();
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a document library.The code that you have used is for a sharepoint list.

To upload a file to document library and update its properties, modify your code as below:

```
string strFilePath = @"PathToMyPDF";
FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();  
newFile.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strFilePath);  
newFile.Overwrite = true;
SP.List targetList = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");  
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = targetList.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);  
ctx.Load(uploadFile);  
ctx.ExecuteQuery();  

uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["Title"] = "Test_title";
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["EAN_x0020_k_x00f3_d"] = "AnotherCodeWhichIsRequired";
uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I pretty much sure that I'm using Sharepoint list with Attachments. Like I said I could create it ,but when I'm click it is shows  empty fields and error [message](https://imgur.com/a/zav2f)

Comment: i tried your code and its working as expected. What type of field is `EAN_x0020_k_x00f3_d` ?

Comment: Hi @GautamSheth thank you for join this issue..Its just a **text** type ..I think the problem is that, when I create that listItem from code it's related to nobody. When I created it online the listItem is related to logged user. But when I try to edit user field which is type **microsoft.sharepoint.client.fieldlookupvalue**, I just can't do that because it's readonly field.